# Бот для беседы ВК

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте

У меня есть бот для беседы ВК (авторизуется под пользователем), но в нем есть то что я не могу увидеть и исправить.
Эти пункты я не могу исправить:

- люди пишут в БЕСЕДУ, а бот отвечает в ЛИЧКУ
- таймауты после простоя и вылет
- иногда требует каптчу и вылетает (вроде исправил, в начале цикла поставил time.sleep(5)

Код:

```
    import time
    import vk_api
    import random
    from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
    #import u_photo
    def write_msg(rand_int, user_id, message):
        vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': rand_int})
    # API-ключ
    token = "ЦЕНЗУРА"
    # Авторизуемся как сообщество
    #vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token, login = 'ЦЕНЗУРА', password = 'ЦЕНЗУРА')
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
    print("Бот запущен")
    # Основной цикл
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            # Если пришло новое сообщение
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:
                    request = event.text
                    randint = random.randint(100000000,900000000)
                    request = request.lower()
                    chat_id = vk.method('messages.getConversations')
                    chat_id = chat_id['items']
                    print(chat_id)
                    for check in request:
                       #id = vk.method('messages.getConversations')
                       #id = id['items'][0]['last_message']['from_id']
                       #print(id)'
                        if request == "привет":
                            write_msg(randint, event.user_id, "Хай")
                        elif request == "пока":
                            write_msg(randint, event.user_id, "Пока :(")
                        else:
                            write_msg(randint, event.user_id, "Не понял...")
```

Comment: вы по идеи сам вывод сообщения не так делаете [вот тут неплохо так описано про чаты](https://habr.com/ru/post/428507/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы писать в беседу, в вашей функции `write_msg` используйте не `user_id`, а `chat_id`.

Подробнее читайте тут: https://vk.com/dev/messages.send

Что касается вылетов, то тут нужно разбираться. Если хотите, можете оформить отдельный вопрос, в котором вам нужно указать полные сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо, статья помогла. Но каптча выдает ошибку :(